# JavaServer faces redirecting form

Tags: forms, jsf, redirect

Hello I have that form:

```
        <h:form>
            <h:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection" value="#{votesBean.answer}">
                <f:converter converterId="PollConverter"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{pollsBean.selectItems}"/>
            </h:selectOneRadio>
            <h:messages/>
            <h:commandButton value="#{msgs.vote}" action="/profile/main.xhtml"/>
        </h:form>
```

But when I submit this form, page no redirects to  main.xhtml, but refresh current page (viewpoll.xhtml, I ‘think because there are errors in form), but not include view parameters. I use view parameter to know current poll… in result I get nullpointer exception, because I don’t have poll id.

Answer (score 1):

- If you would like to navigate directly without validation and conversion, use `immediate="true"` in `h:commandButton`.
- Otherwise, there might be a failure in `Request Processing Life Cycle`, Eg. `validation phase`.
- Finally, your `URL`(/profile/main.xhtml) address is incorrect.